# AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm using ASP.NET Boilerplate (.NET Core v3).

The problem is `Create` function returns "500 Internal Server Error", though `Get` and `GetAll` are working without any problems.

[image: Error on sSwagger]

Below id AppService class Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using BoilerplateTemplate.Entities;
using Abp.Domain.Repositories;
using BoilerplateTemplate.Authorization;
using Abp.Authorization;

namespace BoilerplateTemplate.Products
{
    [AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_Products)]
    public class ProductsAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<Product, ProductDto, int, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, ProductDto>
    {
        public ProductsAppService(IRepository<Product, int> repository) : base(repository)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Below is The Dto Code

```
using Abp.Application.Services.Dto;
using Abp.AutoMapper;
using BoilerplateTemplate.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BoilerplateTemplate.Products.DTOs
{
    [AutoMapFrom(typeof(Product))]
    public class ProductDto:EntityDto<int>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Below is entity code

```
using Abp.Domain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BoilerplateTemplate.Entities
{
    public class Product : Entity<int>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I found in Logs.txt file is related to Mapping:

> Mapping types:
>   **ProductDto -> Product
>   BoilerplateTemplate.Products.DTOs.ProductDto -> BoilerplateTemplate.Entities.Product
>   AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.**

Comment: @aaron yes, its working thank you I've changed [AutoMapFrom(typeof(Product))] to [AutoMap(typeof(Product))]